# How to install Node JS latest version on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, nodejs, versions

Now, the latest version of Node is `20.11.0`. However, every time I tried to install Node, it installed the `12.22.9` version.

This commands is not working, every time it installed the same version `12.22.9`

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

sudo apt install nodejs
```

Comment: The most popular way is to use https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm . Then you can `nvm install 20.11.0` and `nvm use 20.11.0`